# Sort order for model items in django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Say I have a model:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(verbose_name=u'Вопрос', max_length=1024)
    is_free_text = models.BooleanField(verbose_name=u'Ответ в виде текста?')
    sort_order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
```

is there a plugin or something for django admin to have list of models somewhere and move them up and down (or drag and drop) to define their sort order? I basically want every question to have a unique sort order so that they are sorted according to their sort_order where fetched.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of options but you will most likely have to tinker a bit with them. Here are some snippets (I'm not sure how well these will work):

- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2306/
- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2047/
- http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2057/

Some apps that claim to do it:

- https://github.com/ff0000/django-sortable
- https://github.com/centralniak/django-inline-ordering

If you are interested installing [django-grapelli](https://github.com/sehmaschine/django-grappelli) (which is a skin for the entire django admin) , you can make use of [their sortable change list items](http://django-grappelli.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customization.html#inline-sortables)

Comment: I'm not real impressed with django-grapelli, no IE support for 7 or 8 (I have hospital/financial industry clients that are lagging behind on browsers) and it breaks other common use plugins like django-mptt. lastly the css grid system they use is custom and undocumented, so any additional custom admin pages require a huge learning curve to integrate nicely.